# como validar la longitud de 2 o mas jtextfield en un solo metodo?

Tags: java, validación, jtextfield

tengo 2 jtextfield y quiero validar la cantidad de caracteres que escriben en ellos

```
       text_root_username = new JTextField();
       text_root_username.addKeyListener(this);//////
        text_root_password = new JPasswordField();
        text_root_password.addKeyListener(this);
```

los valido con el siguente metodo

```
        @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


          if(text_root_password.getText().length()>=8){
        e.consume();
        }
         if(text_root_username.getText().length()>=8) {
        e.consume();
          }
    }
```

pero lo que pasa es que que cuando uno llega a 8 caracteres no deja que se escriba algun otro caracter en el otro jtext y viseversa

Answer (score 1):

Tendrás que hacer la validación haciendo una captura del componente independientemente del otro, porque si no una vez llegado a ese límite de caracteres en cualquiera de ellos, **`e`** se habrá consumido.

Primero establece un nombre a esos **JTextField**

```
caja1.setName("caja1");
caja2.setName("caja2");
```

Luego en el método `KeyTyped(KeyEvent e)` capturamos el componente de esta manera

```
Component aux = e.getComponent();
```

Y finalmente validamos independientemente cada caja de texto por el nombre el número de caracteres a introducir.

```
if(aux.getName().equals("caja1")){
    if(caja1.getText().length() >= 8){
          e.consume();
    }
}
```